# translating text like "next tuesday 5pm" to dates (similar to google calendar)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datetime

This wouldnt be too hard to code myself, but I'm thinking to myself -- theres got to be some javascript or php library like this already out there...

Basically I want to translate normal speach-like text, such as "next monday", "tomorrow", "Jan 2", "2/15" at 4pm, etc.. into datetimes, similar to how google calendar input is very flexible with what you can input.

Anyone know of any particular libraries like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a JavaScript solution, try http://www.datejs.com/.

It seems to be similar to what you're looking for. It actually didn't work with "next tuesday 5pm" but did work for "tuesday 5pm." It may be possible to add to it to take into possible cases that you think you may need but it doesn't support (like the example you gave).

Answer (score 3):

Php has the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

Examples from the documentation:

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```

Comment: good point. duhh... in cases where its not super friendly, such as misspelling "tomorrow", or "2-18" doesnt work when it should be "2/18", then i could just regex those and change them into the acceptable format.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

in php strtotime can do this, maybe not as good as google though:

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with strtotime();

Just type `strtotime("Next Tuesday");`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php